# Algorithm to get possible combinations

Tags: algorithm

I need an algorithm to get all the possible combinations for 2 characters, in a sequence of 3 characters

Input

```
caractersAllowed[2] = [A,B]
sequenceTable[3] = [0,0,0]
```

Output

```
[A,A,A]
[A,A,B]
[A,B,A]
[A,B,B]
[B,A,A]
[B,A,B]
[B,B,B]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple recursion should do the job:

```
rec(chars, current_word, size){
    if(size == 0) print(current_word);
    else{
        foreach char c in chars{
            rec(chars, current_word + c, size - 1)
        }
    }
}
```

Then, you just need to call `rec([A,B], "", 3)`.